# why does turbostream just render only the turboframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

i don't know why it just render only the html form of the replaced turboframe but not the whole page contain that turboframe

[a string ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCCQd.png)
this is my code

```
render turbo_stream: 
      turbo_stream.replace(
        'active_admin_btn',
        partial: 'shared/admin_btn',
        locals: {user: @user}
      )
```

and log

```
Started POST "/admin/2" for ::1 at 2024-01-16 10:03:24 +0700
Processing by UserController#active_admin as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/session_helper.rb:8:in `current_user'
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_controller.rb:47:in `active_admin'
  TRANSACTION (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/user_controller.rb:48:in `active_admin'
  User Update (1.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1, "admin" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", "2024-01-16 03:03:24.502247"], ["admin", true], ["id", 2]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_controller.rb:48:in `active_admin'
  TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/user_controller.rb:48:in `active_admin'
  Rendered shared/_admin_btn.html.erb (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 441)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms | Allocations: 3905)
```

and the view

```
<turbo-frame id="active_admin_btn">
                <%= render "shared/admin_btn", user: user %>
                </turbo-frame>
```

application.js

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }
```

any help, please
i have tried all the alternative way on ybt

Comment: you probably meant to `turbo_stream.update(` instead

Comment: @Alex yeah, but the problem just the same

Comment: your're showing `partial: 'shared/admin_btn'` the log shows `Rendered shared/_admin_btn.html.erb` - I don't understand what you're trying to do instead, it seems to render exactly what the code says.

Comment: i added the image on top @Alex

Comment: doesn't look like you have `turbo-rails` set up correctly https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails?tab=readme-ov-file#installation

Comment: i use rails 7.0.0, i also switch development to redis but not work

Comment: format support only html, i don't know why @Alex

Comment: what's in your `application.js`? any errors in browser console?

Comment: i added application.js, no error on browser

Comment: do you have `app/javascript/application.js` or `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`?

Comment: sure, i have and also import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"

Comment: ok that looks fine. check if turbo is loaded, in the browser console type: `Turbo`

Comment: there is an error VM95:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: turbo is not defined

Comment: not `turbo`. capitalization: `Turbo`

Comment: yes, i tried both

Comment: do you have `javascript_importmap_tags` in your layout? just make sure your application.js is being loaded, that's all.

Comment: my head tag  <title> <%= full_title(yield(:title))%> </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>

Comment: can you check what's being loaded in application.js from the network tab. that's about the last thing that could be wrong here.

Comment: just the turbo doc, no js loaded

Comment: sorry, not sure what else to ask you here. make sure you don't have any precompiled asstes `bin/rails assets:clobber`. "no js loaded" - what exactly is loaded? you might want to start a new rails app so you can compare your setup.